# windows EnumProcesses some process names as <unknown>

Tags: c++, winapi, process, pid, enumerate

Hello I have [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-processes) sample code running which uses x to print processNames and PIDS of all currently running processes. Only some of them display an actual name though, with others displaying as  (as seen in my output image below)

[image]

I was wondering if this was expected behavior, and that not all processes have a name (I could see this being the case for minimal background processes), or if I was using the EnumProcesses function incorrectly.

My code is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>


//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-processes
void PrintProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID ){
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
    // Get a handle to the process.
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID );
    // Get the process name.
    if (NULL != hProcess ){
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;
        if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded) ){
            GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
        }
    }
    // Print the process name and identifier.
    _tprintf( TEXT("%s  (PID: %u)\n"), szProcessName, processID );
    // Release the handle to the process.
    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}

//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/psapi/enumerating-all-processes
int main( void ){
    // Get the list of process identifiers.
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;
    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) ){
        return 1;
    }
    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
    // Print the name and process identifier for each process.
    //for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ ){
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        if( aProcesses[i] != 0 )        {
            _tprintf( TEXT("aProcesses[%u] = %u (process ID)\n"), i, aProcesses[i] );
            PrintProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] );
            ListProcessThreads( aProcesses[i] );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: EnumProcesses doesn't yield process names. It's the other parts of the code that deal with names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess), `OpenProcess` fails for idle and CSRSS processes.

> If the specified process is the Idle process or one of the CSRSS
>   processes, this function fails and the last error code is
>   `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` because their access restrictions prevent
>   user-level code from opening them.

You have to enable `SeDebugPrivilege` (and also run your application with admin privileges). Moreover, if your application is compiled as 32-bit, it cannot access 64-bit processes with `OpenProcess`

If you just want a list of running processes, use `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` to list running processes.

```
#define UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

int main()
{
    wprintf(L"Start:\n");
    HANDLE hndl = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, 0);
    if(hndl)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32  process = { sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32) };
        Process32First(hndl, &process);
        do
        {
            wprintf(L"%8u, %s\n", process.th32ProcessID, process.szExeFile);
        } while(Process32Next(hndl, &process));

        CloseHandle(hndl);
    }
}
```

Side note, it is recommended to compile the program as Unicode. Avoid `_txxx` macros such as `_tprintf` etc.